# PHP trim non-letters Unicode

Tags: php, utf-8, trim

I need to trim a string of all characters *except* letters from any languages in UTF-8. For an early test this was working fine until obviously I started using UTF-8 non-Latin letters:

```
<?php
$s = '\$5ı龢abc';
echo '<p>'.$s.'</p>';
while (!preg_match('/([\p{L}]+)/u', $s[0]))
{
 $s = substr($s, 1);
 echo '<p>'.$s.'</p>';
}
?>
```

This currently outputs the following:

> $5ı龢abc
>
> $5ı龢abc
>
> 5ı龢abc
>
> ı龢abc
>
> �龢abc
>
> 龢abc
>
> ��abc
>
> �abc
>
> abc

I would like the final output to be: `ı龢abc`. I'm not quite sure what I'm missing however?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using individual character indexing doesn't work, since PHP isn't aware of "characters" in strings, and merely indexes bytes. This is obviously a problem with multi-byte characters. But you're doing it way too manually anyway; just replace [all non-letter characters at the beginning of the string](https://regex101.com/r/ifQMOl/1):

```
$s = preg_replace('/^\P{L}*/u', '', $s);
```

Comment: Great, that works, thank you! I'll accept after the site allows it.

Comment: Why reducing it to only the beginning? Why is OP okay with that? Are roman numerals considered to be wanted (because they're contructed thru letters) or not (because their overall meaning is numeric)?

Comment: That’s what OP did, @Amigo, so I assume they’re okay with it, yeah. If trimming from both sides is needed, that’s a slightly adjusted regex.